# Getting Teams Context information in SharePoint Framework extensions

Tags: spfx, spfx-extensions

With SPFx 1.7 preview release, I know we can access Teams Context information in SharePoint Framework web part but not from SharePoint Framework extensions. I looked at ApplicationCustomizerContext class but didn't find any reference. Wondering if Teams context information is available in SharePoint Framework extensions?

Answer (score 4):

Interestingly I found the way to get Teams Context information in SPFx extension. Follow the below steps to do it:

1. Do "npm install @microsoft/teams-js --save" in your SPFx extension project.
2. In your .ts file or if you using React, then inside your target component, import microsoftTeams names as 'Import * as microsoftTeams from '@microsoft/teams-js'.
3. In your code, use below code:

   ```
       try {
           microsoftTeams.initialize();
           microsoftTeams.getContext(tContext => {
               console.log('Inside Teams:'+tContext.teamName);
               this.setState({ ShowBanner: false });
           });

       } catch (error) {
           console.error("Exception while getting Teams context:" + error);
       }
   ```

Comment: Amazing, thanks for this :D

Comment: is this correct way ? . however code is working